# Getting very odd startup error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a very simple program:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace NS
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(2000)));
                //get some content using Console.ReadLine() and prompting using Console.WriteLine();
                string HTML =
                string.Format(@"HTML redacted", someFormatString, w/e);
                Clipboard.SetText(HTML);
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                string JS = string.Format(@"JS redacted", someFormatString, w/e);
                Clipboard.SetText(JS);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sidenote: Yes I know that wrapping a try/catch around Main isn't preferred, but I need it for debbugging purposes right now.

I'm referencing all the right assemblies, here's the assembly references in the csproj:

```
<Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
```

However, when I try to load it from Explorer, it comes up with 0xc000142. I don't know what it means, though.

Works perfectly if I load it from CMD, though.

Any ideas? I've tried adding references, changing to the System.Windows Clipboard class, making a new project and copying the code in, nothing's had an effect.

EDIT: As this doesn't seem to be clear: THIS IS A CONSOLE APP THAT HAPPENS TO NEED TO USE THE CLIPBOARD CLASS IN FORMS. IT'S NOT AN ATTEMPT TO BE A FORMS/CLI APP.

Comment: google the this `0xc000142` and it will tell you what the error means also what are the values in this line `string HTML = string.Format(@"HTML redacted", someFormatString, w / e);`

Comment: What is your project output type ?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Read it, not helpful at all.

Comment: @user957902 Executable Console Application.

Comment: well how are you launching the app console vs GUI sounds like you need to look at how to use `StartUpInfo` class can't really tell because you are only showing ConsoleApp code here

Comment: Maybe you should use Environment.UserInteractive to see whether you can use the Console operations?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm ONLY using the Clipboard class in Forms. THIS IS PURELY A CONSOLE APP.

Comment: look here for 2 examples one is basic the other is more complex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944605/c-sharp-clipboard-gettext

Comment: Main method is set as [STAThread].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT after comments*:

Well sounds like there is an issue with your machine. Here is a release build of my test program, it runs on my machine. If it does not run on yours, you've got a corrupt .net installation or something like that going on. I suggest try on another computer also.

It's .net 4.5 btw.

If anyone else can confirm it works, and I am not crazy, that would be awesome :)

```
http://23.23.250.9/ClipboardInConsole.zip
```

Note that just for the clipboard to work, you only need to reference

```
System
System.Windows.Forms
```

Not sure what you need all the others for, but for just the clipboard, those 2 are enough, the project still builds and runs. Good luck!

---

*My original answer:*

Needs to be Single Thread Apartment Mode to work correctly. Add the following attribute and that should work. **Note this answer was posted before the OP edit having added [STAThread] in the question.**

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
```

**Note:** If you add a `Console.ReadKey();` inside your catch block, you'll see that error. You also only need a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

**Note 2:** If it still doesn't work you have another error that you're not seeing. Try my suggestion of adding Console.ReadKey() inside the Catch{} block and see the exception.

My (your) full code that compiles and works:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace NS
{

    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(2000)));
                //get some content using Console.ReadLine() and prompting using Console.WriteLine();
                string HTML = "<html>";
                //string.Format(@"HTML redacted", someFormatString, w / e);
                Clipboard.SetText(HTML);
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                string JS = "JS { }";//string.Format(@"JS redacted", someFormatString, w / e);
                Clipboard.SetText(JS);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. It works for me, let me post full code and you can try it:

Comment: Full code is this, and a bunch of Console.WriteLines + ReadLines and ReadKeys. Oh, and a small capitalize method that uses a StringBuilder. And also, it works from VS, and CMD, but not from Explorer.

Comment: That is the whole code. No more, no less. Apart from the mentioned readlines, readkeys and writelines, replace and capitalize method.

Comment: @ofstream it's not the whole code because your code as-is doesn't compile. 'someFormatString' doesn't exist. Likely when you took stuff out, you took out the cause of the error. I suggest (a) Try my code above as a "baseline", (b) add 'Console.ReadKey()' inside 'catch{}' block, and finally (c) add lines from your real program and see when you get an error. This is basic troubleshooting, you can't go wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does. You've got something else going on then. Anyone else want to copy my code and confirm it works?

Comment: Are you sure it works, when run off file explorer? I've noted it works fine off VS and CMD.

Comment: Yes I executed it from explorer

Comment: Odd. Wait for one second, I'll try restarting.

Comment: Nope, restarting didn't affect anything.

Comment: @ofstream I posted the actual release build try and run it. I think next try and repair/reinstall .net on your machine.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your visual studio settings for compilation. If you have another computer, install a fresh visual studio on it and try to compile. Bizarre issue, has to be some setting or config but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: Got it. Seems like moving it to a new project wasn't enough, it needed to be a new project with a new name. I have no idea why. But problem solved. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I have some few options for you:

1) Try to run your Visual Studio on Administrator Mode. Right Click VS icon -> Run as Adminitrator. Let me know if this will work.

2) Check your project settings and make sure that it is built with "Any CPU" selected.