# UWP: Ask for Clipboard acces from Background Task

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows

I develop an app who paste content to the clipboard from it's background task.

```
public sealed class ToastBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask {
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
        //Inside here developer can retrieve and consume the pre-defined 
        //arguments and user inputs;
        var toastArgs = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;
        var argument = toastArgs.Argument;
        SetClipbordContent(toastArgs.Argument);
    }
    public static void SetClipbordContent(string text) {
        var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
        dataPackage.SetText(text);
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
}
```

But when I execute the line

```
Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```

raise this exeption:

```
The activation of a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000001D)
```

An usual workaround to handle this secario in classic .Net Framework is to use the Thread class to execute this portion of code in a STA context ([C# Clipboard.GetText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944605/c-sharp-clipboard-gettext)) But I don't know how to do this in UWP.

Comment: Afaik this is unfortunately not possible. Bg tasks should not do foreground stuff and thus such things are not allowed. I also wish one could at least set the clipboard for several great use cases like 2FA or password manager integration into Cortana.

Comment: Here is a similar thread([Set Clipboard content in Cortana background task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960822/set-clipboard-content-in-cortana-background-task)) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in the past to execute on the UI thread from a background thread...

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => {
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full answer based on [@Edd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509328/uwp-ask-for-clipboard-acces-from-background-task/60549507#60549507)'s answer:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core;

...

public static void SetClipbordContent(string text) {
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
                        dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
                        dataPackage.SetText(text);
                        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
                    });
}
```